# send a pull request of one commit done after others

Tags: git, github

i'm working on a big code change, and doing tons of commits on my fork of the repository.

in the middle of my work, i improved some code that is not related to this change, and that i want to submit as a pull request right away.

currently the tree for my fork looks like this (using letters instead of commit ids for simplicity)

```
fork/master:
A ->  B -> C -> D -> E

upstream/master:
A
```

what is the easiest way to pick change `C` and submit as a pull request?

i tried branching from A on my fork and then cherry-pick C, but it also brings in B changes.

I know that git treats C as a the path A-B-C and not as a single changeset... my question here is how would you massage the repo with a new branch to have a pull request with C changes right now? The goal is "submit a pull request, doesn't matter from which new branch, to upstream/master with only the C changes"

i then tried naively to:

```
git checkout fork/master   
git diff A..C file_i_care_that_was_only_changed_on_C > patch
git checkout A
git checkout -b temp_for_pull
git apply < patch
# lots of errors. changes do not get applied.
```

ideas?

Comment: C has no dependencies on B?  Can you `git rebase -i A` and swap the lines for commit B and C and have it succeed without merge conflicts?

Comment: @AndrewC i only use rebase to flatten merges. what should i do for the `rebase -i`? i tried removed all the pick lines leaving only the one i wanted, but the end result just picked all commits regardless

Comment: When you are in the rebase screen swap the location of B and C (cut/delete/kill the entire line for B, and then paste/yank it below C).   Leave everything else alone except for that.  When it loads up it should have B->C->D->E, change it to C->B->D->E.  Leave everything as "pick"

Comment: awesome. let me try that!

Comment: If you are correct that C has no dependencies on B it should work.  Given that your first cherry-pick seems to have failed I am not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(See AndrewC comment above for a solution with interactive rebase.)

I have to do this often so i'm always revisiting this... my latest solution is to use

(again, using letters instead of commitIDs for simplicity)

`git format-patch B...C [optional file list]`

this will generate a file `0001_C_commit_message.patch`

and then, on a new branch made out of `A`:

`git am 0001-b_to_c_changes.patch`

now, commit, push, create pull request.